# Changing values of inputs via checkbox change event

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a page which has two check boxes with different id's along with a text box in different `div` and radio group consisting of 4 radio buttons in another `div`. What I'm trying to achieve is:

**If user checks the first checkbox the following should happen**

1. checkbox two to be disabled
2. textbox to have a value of 0 and made readonly
3. first radio selected and rest hidden along with their labels

**If user unchecks the first checkbox the the above steps should be revereted.**

**If user checks the second checkbox the following should happen**

1. checkbox one to be disabled
2. textbox to have value of 1 abd made readonly
3. first radio selected and rest hidden along with their labels

**If user unchecks the second checkbox the the above steps should be revereted.**

I have come up with the following code

```
$("#firstCheckBox").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#secondCheckBox').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#spinner').val('0');
        $('#spinner').prop('readonly', true);
        $('#radio_id:first').prop('checked', true);
        $('#radio_id:not(:checked)').hide();

    } else {
        $('#secondCheckBox').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#spinner').val('');
        $('#spinner').prop('readonly', false);
        $('#radio_id:first').prop('checked', false);
        $('#radio_id:not(:checked)').show();
    }
});
$("#secondCheckBox").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#firstCheckBox').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#spinner').val('1');
        $('#spinner').prop('readonly', true);
        $('#radio_id:first').prop('checked', true);
        $('#radio_id:not(:checked)').hide();

    } else {
        $('#firstCheckBox').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#spinner').val('');
        $('#spinner').prop('readonly', false);
        $('#radio_id:first').prop('checked', false);
        $('#radio_id:not(:checked)').show();
    }
});
```

So my question, is there a better way of doing this or am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use `classes` and `$(this)` and you will see that you need only one `change` event. Also, are you really sure about `#radio_id:first` ??? Do you have multiple ids that are the same? You shouldn't.

Comment: Since this works and you're looking for input on improving it, this question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
var $targetCheckBoxes = $("#firstCheckBox,#secondCheckBox");
$targetCheckBoxes.change(function () {
  var isChecked = this.checked;
  var currentElement = this;
  $targetCheckBoxes.filter(function(){
    return  this.id  != currentElement.id;
  }).prop('disabled', isChecked );
  $('#spinner').val( isChecked  ? this.value : '');
  $('#spinner').prop('readonly', isChecked);
  $('#radio_id').toggle(isChecked).prop('checked', isChecked );
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2db85yL0/)**

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just tried this and it get an error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: Thanks, but the radio button are a group of 4 and I want to check the first 1 and hide all the other 3 along with their labels on checkbox checked and on checkbox unchecked I want to uncheck the radio and display all along with their labels

Comment: You should not have duplicate ids for element. `$('#radio_id:first')` is irrelevant as `$('#radio_id')` will only select first element having that id. You should rather use same class and then use class selector along with `:first`  to target first element in set.

Comment: I can add a class no problem. But how will the label hide and show the label test next to each radio button

Comment: This is what I've come up with `$('.radio-class:first').prop('checked', isChecked)
        $('.radio-class).not(':checked').toggle(!isChecked).siblings('label').not(':first').toggle(!isChecked);` anyway I can chain the whole thing in one line?

Comment: @Code: can not optimize much other than reusing elements object http://jsfiddle.net/fdm3e094/

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for all your help and support I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad it helps :)